# How to Tag a single file in GIT

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

I am very new to git. I am currently trying to get familiarized with it by using it to track changes in some excel files that I am maintaining to track some continuous activity I am involved with. All the files are in a single repository. I want to tag each file separately with their versions. Is this possible? So far what I found was the capability to tag the entire repository. If what I am trying to do is wrong, do advise me on the best practice.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

When I was doing this I deliberately deleted a previous tag to make the entire repository be tagged( as I did not find a way to tag single files) as v1.0. As I now want to reset the name of the tag with the file name and quite comfortable with the way things should happen, how can I rollback the deletion and rename the previous tag (the deleted tag)?

Comment: `git` tags commits. Not files. Can you tell us what you want to do with these "tags"? I think a more appropriate answer would be possible then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are placed on specific commits as opposed to the repository as a whole as you suggest in your question.

One way of doing what you are suggesting is making sure you only commit changes to a single file with each commit, then you can tag that commit with eg. `file1-v1.0` to represent v1.0 of file1.

What are you trying to represent by tagging these commits though? That will influence any advice on how to better your process.

Comment: thanks. As I said in my question as well my primary interest is to get to know more about the git environment. But at this particular instance what I am trying to do is to track a specific milestone which I meant to achieve in maintaining the document. For example: when I finish doing the initial work I tag it as v1.0, when I complete going through the document with the others and do all the necessary changes I want to make it v2.0 etc. In essence if I make one commit as v1.0 and another on another file as v2.0 then I will not be achieving this. In fact both should be v1.0

Answer (score 11):

Technically you can tag the content of a single file without it's file name. But such tags are of limited use. Tags are expected to point to commits, and special tags to non-commits have very different behavior (you can't git checkout such a special tag). So I strongly suggest to never use non-commit tags.

When you want only some files to be tagged, it might be better to use a separate repo for them, or at least different branches, since git always looks at the full tree for it's operations.

If you still insist to create such a special tag you do:

```
> git ls-tree HEAD
040000 tree 2c186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b    bar
100644 blob 409940768f2a684935a7d15a29f96e82c487f439    foo.txt

> git tag my-bar-tree 2c186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b
> git tag my-foo-file 409940768f2a684935a7d15a29f96e82c487f439
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only tag a commit, e.g. a certain snap shot in the history of your repository. However, git stores the files as blobs and what you can do is to use **git notes** to add a note to a blob, like this:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 252f7c7df5bd181536a6c9d0f9c371ce1a5dd042    .gitignore
100644 blob 8150ada74aba86c983ac3f8f63ab26aaa76fdcb7    README
100644 blob c4b1ff6dcb2a8e50727df21ced8d2872cd91af79    TODO.txt

$ git notes add -m "Adding a note to TODO" c4b1ff6dcb2a8e507
$ git notes show c4b1ff6dcb2a8e507
Adding a note to TODO
```

However, note that this note (no pun intended :) )is only attached to this blob, so whenever the file changes a new blob will be created (with another sha1 hash value) and the new blob will not have this note.

Comment: Considering your ending note (about the changing SHA after a file change): This looks to me like this *is* the intended behaviour. No?

Answer (score 2):

You should really explore having separate branches that track changes to specific files. You should be able to work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.

A tag is a pointer to a specific revision of the repository.  The individual files do not themselves have versions separate from that of the repository.  If you want separate versions, your options are to have a separate repository for each file, have a separate branch for each file, or to use a different tool that is file oriented (such as RCS -- though it lacks many of the nice features git has).

If the files are at all related, you generally do want to tag a specific version of the group of them. If they're not, you can still tag the entire group with the version of each file changed in that revision.  Restricting changes to one file per revision can make this process easier to manage.

Comment: thanks, in fact what you've suggested finally is what I thought of doing. Further I have been committing changes only on the basis of one file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer  to the  original  question, but instead an  answer to one of the comments on that original question

> git tags commits. Not files. Can you tell us what you want to do with
> these "tags"? I think a more appropriate answer would be possible
> then. – Noufal Ibrahim

I am posting this extended comment as a pseudo-answer

- because stackoverflow's  comments have limited formatting.
- and because I don't feel it is appropriate for me to add my explanation of why *I*  want single file or subset tagging  to the OP question,  in case it is not the same

BRIEF ANSWER:

> When I do a diff between **tag-for-code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st** and
> **tag-for-code.txt--original-version-by-joe**
> I only want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt**.
> Or perhaps **my-lib/import/new-module**.
> I don't want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/module1**,
> which is supposedly completely independent[*] of
> **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt*.
> No, I don't want to have to know what  parts I should filter out.  I may not know that  without digging deeper.

I understand that  git tags are for commits, and commits are essentially snapshots of the entire repository.  So I'm just asking for a workaround that would allow me  to have the convenience of saying `... diff tag1 tag2`
refer only to the subset of files that are  explicitly identified as belonging to tag1 and tag2,  and not all a  whole slew of other independent files  that happened to have been changed between.

E.g. perhaps I should have a  hypothetical  subset tag  create a file containing a list of filenames and the repo commit ID.  So then tools that use such subset tags  would filter  only information relevant to the list of filenames in their respective tag-files. Or perhaps just blob-IDs. Whatever.

Has anyone got a BKM for  doing this?

===

I am posting this as a pseudo-answer because I have long suffered intellectual pain because of this lack of
single file or subset tagging in git. Surely there is a git
equivalent? Although I suspect that there is not because of the
amazing number of off target responses, often of the form "why do you
want to do that?"

Some other version control systems have both entire repo and single
file or subset tagging. AFAICT git does not.  Without loss of
generality I will provide an example from CVS, although these concepts
apply to DVCS just as well.

## Brief  summary of why you want  single file  and subset group of file tagging as well as whole repo tagging

We all agree that symbolic tag games are good. Right?

In the bad old  days there were only single file tags.
Although usually you can apply the same tag to groups of files, it was not guaranteed that you apply the same tag to the entire repository.

So if you did *checkout -rTestsRunTag*
expecting  to be able to build and run the tests successfully
it might fail,  because some file that you did not know you depended on was not tagged with *TestsRunTag*.

Hence the preference for  whole repository tags.
Tags  that apply to a snapshot of the whole repository.
Hopefully, if you check out such a whole repository tag, you're guaranteed to be able to build successfully.  Right? ...

Actually not right.   Did you put your build tools, compiler, etc. in your repository?

Nevertheless, whole repository tagging  was a very good step towards reproducible builds and tests.

nevertheless^2,  VCSes  that's apply only whole repository tagging  throw the baby out with the bathwater.

There is still a need for single file tagging.  More often, group of
file tagging where the group is not the entire repo.  Typically a
directory subtree, or if you related such things.

Basically,  you need such subset tagging  when the tag is relevant only to  a subset. When the tag is irrelevant and even confusing to the entire repo.

Or when using a whole repo tag  is inconvenient.

As I try to explain in the example below
when I do a diff between **code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st** and **code.txt--original-version-by-joe**
I only want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt**.
Or perhaps **my-lib/import/new-module**.
but I don't want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/module1**,  which is supposedly completely independent of **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt*.

## Brief(?)  example  of wanting non-full repo tagging

Here's a brief example, that  has just prompted me to search for and post this.

I have a  library of  mostly independent things. Call this my-lib

I have collected many modules from around the web that I put in this library,
in places like my-lib/import/module1, my-lib/import/module2.
Keeping them separate from each other
and from my own stuff like my-lib/my-stuff-my-module1,  and so on.

I am adding a new module to this library,  that I have imported off some website.
Let's call that my-lib/import/new-module

Unfortunately that module does not have its own version control system.
It was posted on a discussion thread,  with slightly different versions by different users.
I'm not quite sure which version I want use so I'm going to  put a few of them in my library

WLOG  let me just talk about a  single file in the module
my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt

So I download first version  I find on the discussion thread.
Place it into my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt.
Check it in.
I would like to give it a symbolic name,
since  that is nicer than using either git hashes
or  numeric version numbers like CVS's 1.1.1.1.
How about perhaps symbolic "tag" name code.txt--original-version-by-joe
although I'm just as likely to put some dates  like original creation date in the tag name
as well as an  the file commit message, and ideally more comments associated with a description of the tag.
and I don't need to have the filename in the tag, it's just an example.

Perhaps I use this for a while. But eventually I see a different version on the discussion thread.
Next I download first version  I find on the discussion thread.
Place it into my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt.
Check it in.
I would like to give it a different symbolic name.
How about code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st.

I hope that this is sufficient to show why I want tags that apply to single files, or subsets of files, and not to the entire repository.

The tags *code.txt--original-version-by-joe* and *code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st* are relevant only to
the module **my-lib/import/new-module**
and its file **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt**.
These new-module tags are  irrelevant to other  modules of which it is completely independent, such as
**my-lib/import/module1**, **my-lib/import/module2**, **my-lib/my-stuff-my-module1**.

When I do a diff between **code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st** and **code.txt--original-version-by-joe**
I only want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt**.
Or perhaps **my-lib/import/new-module**.
but I don't want to see diffs for **my-lib/import/module1**,  which is supposedly completely independent[*] of **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt*.

## Note: There is no such thing as completely independent, but...

Note that I said "supposedly  completely independent".
That's the gotcha.
Even completely independent library  modules
may break the library infrastructure for crosscutting stuff like makefiles,
even if they are never linked into the same program.

But nevertheless,
it  is very convenient to have the default
diff between **code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st** and **code.txt--original-version-by-joe**
only show diffs for **my-lib/import/new-module/code.txt**.
and not for Supposedly completely independent **my-lib/import/module1**.

It is also convenient  have ways of saying
"diff against the snapshot of the entire repository at the time that the single file tag
**code.txt--update-by-jim-April1st**
was created.
That's unambiguous if there's only a single file tag.

Minor issues arise  if that same tag is applied to  versions of multiple files
That do not reside in a single  entire repository snapshot (e.g. git commit).
but you can deal with that.

## Why not use modules?

I can hear some <s>idiots</s>, ahem, people of less imagination say
"why not just use modules?"
Talking not about the generic programming division of the program into modules and submodules, but modules and submodules specifically in the version control system,
like git modules and submodules.

OK,  I just used modules in the above example to simplify the discussion.

Modules as defined by the version control system have some overhead.
You have to set things up a priori.
That is  frequently not good enough.

Many  systems start off as a single file in some big parent repository
when they are not considered to be a separate module.
and then evolve into being a separate moduke.
Heck, they  often start as a single function in a *big_file_of_many_functions.c*
You then realize that this function and/or  some near relatives should be in a file by themselves,
like *foo.c*,  and if you're in C/C++ nearly always need  a header file *foo.h*.
eventually you realize that it would be really better if there is a separate directory *foo/*
containing *foo/foo.c* and *foo/foo.h*.
And eventually you may add   *foo/Makefile*, *foo/tests/test1.py*

and somewhere along this evolution from function  within a bigger file of other functions
to a subtree
you decide to give it a version control system modular submodule.

That's great.
But it sure would be nice to have ways of referring
(a) to this set of related things within the bigger repository
(b) and two versions of this set of related things.

I say again:

Modules as defined by the version control system have some overhead.
Considerable overhead.

It is not just me saying this.
This is very much related to the debate about mono repo versus multi-repo,
e.g. https://johnclarke73.medium.com/mono-or-multi-repo-6c3674142dfc.
Some very important software developers and companies use mino-repos.
IMHO in part because *git and other VCS  module systems  are a hassle*.

## Consider a tree  where every subdirectory tree is a separate module

I have long maintained  a personal library.
It is a directory tree, deeply nested.
Nearly every subdirectory tree can be treated as an independent module.
Often individual files can be exported  individually, e.g *header-only librares* in C or C++.
usually I prefer to have a directory for each minimal logical subsystem,
so that you can have separate makefiles and test scripts.

I often share this code with  other projects, companies, employers...

These other projects  seldom want to import my entire personal library tree.
Hence I want to be able to checkout  Just a subset,
ranging from a single file,
most often a subdirectory tree
but sometimes  a set of subdirectory trees that are required to work together.

These other projects often do not want to use my version control system. Too bad, that's life.
But sometimes they do.

Of course,  modern DVCS's have very poor support for checking  out arbitrary subsets.
Short of module support (see elsewhere).
It is not good when a sparse checkout,  sometimes called a sparse branch
(although terminology quickly gets into the weeds of particular version control systems)
carries  history related to items that are not part of what was checked out.
or if not that, if that sparse branch  that is not carrying excess history  and access objects
cannot be merged back into  a repository that has more objects in different parts the file system that were not checked out, and for history.

When they are willing to share version control systems, it is really confusing
to have  the items that they have checked out be tagged with tags that are absolutely irrelevant to them.

Sometimes not just  confusing.
Sometimes a security hole.

Anyway,  in this great big personal monorepo
I like to tag the subsets  checked out by other projects,
and imported back from those other projects.
But, again, those tags are irrelevant to the stuff that those other projects  don't want to look at.

## e.g. CVS tags = per-file but easy to do multiple file

CVS tags actually are defined on a per file basis. But it is common,
and CVS makes it easy, to apply the same tag through multiple files,
to a subtree of the repo, or to the entire repo.  e.g.  if you just
say `cvs tag tagname` in a particular directory, CVS applies the tag
to all files in that directory and its subdirectories. If you say `cvs tag tagname` at the top of your CVS repository, the tag is applied to
your entire repository. Many CVS users have an alias or command that
allows you to tag the entire repository even if you are in a
subdirectory.  but you can also specify a single file `cvs tag single-file`, or multiple independent files and subdirectories `cvs tag foo/file1-only bar/file2-only bazz-tree`

Of course the CVS tags are not guaranteed to be consistent across the repository the way git tags are.

But it's a usage model  question.
Sometimes you want guaranteed cross repository consistent tags.
Sometimes you don't.
Often one uses naming conventions to differentiate the two.
And tools to determine if those naming conventions are correctly applied, e.g. if for example a supposedly whole repository tag has not been applied to everything.