# Tag specific files in git

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am new git, I want to tag specific files from branch.
Example: I have 
`file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4` in `master` and tagged these 4 files as `V1.0` for my initial release

Now I have added `file5` in next release and merged into `master`.
I have to tag only `file5` in new tag as `V2.0` not all the previous files (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`).
Can this can be done in git?

Can anyone help me how to do this in git or any other solution where I can update my every release of my project?

Comment: A tag in Git is synonymous with a commit, which represents groups of files, not individual ones.  I suspect that you don't even need the feature about which you are asking.  If you clarify why you think you need this, maybe we can give a more direct answer.

Comment: It *is* possible to tag a tree or a blob, but it rarely makes any sense to do so. Note that tagging a blob *does not* save a path name, as the blob is identified by its hash value. Tagging a tree would allow you to save a path name, but you might as well use the more-convenient machinery and just tag a commit. You can make a commit that has no history: the tag itself will preserve the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this can be done in git?

No, considering a tag represent (generally, see below) a commit (which is a reference to the *all* repo content, not to a file or a delta)

[image: http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/media/12-4.png]
<sup>Picture from [Git Plumbing](http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/plumbing)</sup>

You can [list the files which have changed between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552353/6309) though:

```
git diff --name-only v1.0 v2.0
```

To list only *new* files, add `--diff-filter=A`:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A v1.0 v2.0
```

That would return '`f5`'.

---

As mentioned in "[How to Tag a single file in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961937/6309)", you can technically tag a single file or a single tree:

```
> git ls-tree HEAD
040000 tree 2c186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b    bar
100644 blob 409940768f2a684935a7d15a29f96e82c487f439    foo.txt

> git tag my-bar-tree 2c186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b
> git tag my-foo-file 409940768f2a684935a7d15a29f96e82c487f439
```

But any non-commit tag is won't be used as a regular commit tag (you canot checkout it for instance).
Possible usage for those non-commit tags: "[Why git tag a blob or a tree (or a tag)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36113180/6309)".

Comment: Instead of tags can I create release_branches for each release of the project?

Comment: @vikv a branch, like a tag, will reference a commit. Not a file. The difference is that, with a branch you can start making new modification and adding commits, while a tag is immutable and keep referencing the same commit.

Comment: thnks for your response, make sense.