# How can I get a list of tags with the first line of the summary?

Tags: git, tags

`git tag` only shows the following for me:

```
v1.0
v2.0
v3.0
v4.0
v5.0
v7.10
v7.2
v7.3
v7.4
v7.5
v7.6
v7.7
v7.8
v7.9
```

`git tag --sort="v:refname" -l` is at least sorted the right way (although I'd prefer the reverse order).

But is there something similar to

```
git log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline
```

Except for the fact that it does not print the log but make something like `less` does (I'm not sure how it is called), I like it. So it would be good if that was displayed when I enter `git tag`.

Comment: Do you mean the problem with the `log` command is that it launches a pager rather than just dumping the output to the console?  Then add the `--no-pager` option (`git --no-pager log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline`)

Comment: Yes! That looks good! (aaah, pager is the name. makes sense)

Comment: Do keep in mind `log` output is (generally) driven by walking history, not necessarily tracking down tags.  OTOH I don't know that the `tag` command can print the info you want (especially because a tag might point at something other than a commit).  Depending on what you know about where the tags are, that may be no big deal; but in the most general case, you might have to include `--all --full-history` in the log command (to make sure tagged commits are traversed) and then feed the output to `grep` to filter down to tagged commits

Comment: "especially because a tag might point at something other than a commit" - what could that be?

Comment: Any git object.  Another tag (but not a lightweight tag).  A `TREE` (a directory listing within a commit).  A `BLOB` (content for a file).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that! What are the usecases for tagging those?

Comment: Generally it gives you a way to bookmark and/or attach notes to a file or directory listing.  It's not that commonly used (because for everyday work it's not necessarily that useful).  Some people take a stab at "why" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112726/why-git-tag-a-blob-or-a-tree-or-a-tag ...

Comment: But like I said, it's not something I find that useful, and in fact I've never used it.  I only point it out because knowing that a tag doesn't necessarily point to a commit, it's clear(er) why the `git tag` command doesn't do much in the way of telling you about the commit (the way `log` does)

Comment: If you turned those comments into an answer, I would upvote it :-)

Comment: Well, I put my response in comments bc it's somewhat tangent to the question - just addressing your comments about the command you were trying.  Figured someone else might know something I missed, and provide a more direct answer... and it looks like they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git tag --list -n1
```

I even have an alias

```
tags = tag --list -n1
```

I mean aliases in git:

```
git config --global alias.tags 'tag --list -n1'
```

Now you can do `git tags`.

Comment: Well, I meant git alias: `git config --global alias.tags 'tag --list -n1'`. Now you can do `git tags`.